# Spring Boot 3.X Hibernate and Oracle Graph DB ojdbc11, unable to connect

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, oracle-graph

nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error accessing tables metadata
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-17008: Closed connection
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-17909: Socket channel is closed.
These nested exceptions definitely point towards database server connectivity.

Comment: application.properties
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/GRAPH
#spring.datasource.username=123
#spring.datasource.password=123
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
#spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
#spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=false
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
#spring.datasource.type=oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource